# Multidimensional array problem in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to use a multidimensional array in VHDL and I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work properly.  My issue is that I've got an array of 17, of 16 vectors, of a given size.  What I want to do is create 17 registers that are array of 16 * std_logic_vector of 32 bits (which = my b, 512).  So, I'm trying to pass in something to input and output on the register instantiation that tells the compiler/synthesizer that I want to pass in something that is 512 bits worth...  Similar to in C if I had:

```
int var[COLS][ROWS][ELEMENTS];
memcpy(&var[3].. // I'm talking about 3rd COL here, passing in memory that is ROWS*ELEMENTS long
```

(My actual declaration is here:)

type partial_pipeline_registers_type is array (0 to 16, 0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(iw - 1 downto 0);
   signal h_blk_pipelined_input : partial_pipeline_registers_type;

I tried simply using h_blk_pipelined_input(0) .. up to (16) but this doesn't work.  I get the following error, which makes me see that I need to double index in to the array:

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:821 - (at the register) Wrong index type for h_blk_pipelined_input.
```

So then I tried what's below, and I get this error:

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - (at the register code). parse error, unexpected TO, expecting COMMA or CLOSEPAR


  instantiate_h_pipelined_reg : regn
   generic map ( N=> b, init => bzeros )
   port map ( clk => clk , rst => '0', en => '1',
      input => h_blk_pipelined_input((i - 1), 0 to 15),
      output=> h_blk_pipelined_input((i),     0 to 15));
-- Changing 0 to 15 to (0 to 15) has no effect...
```

I'm using XST, and from their documentation (http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx6/books/data/docs/xst/xst0067_9.html), the above should have worked:

```
...declaration:

subtype MATRIX15 is array(4 downto 0, 2 downto 0)
   of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

 A multi-dimensional array signal or variable can be completely used:

Just a slice of one row can be specified:

MATRIX15 (4,4 downto 1) <= TAB_B (3 downto 0);
```

One alternative is that I can create more  registers that are 16 times smaller, and instead of trying to do all '0 to 15' at once, I would just do that 15 additional times.  However, I think this may lead to inefficiency in synthesis and I don't feel like this is the right solution.

**EDIT:**

Tried what Ben said,

```
instantiate_h_m_qa_pipeline_registers: for i in 1 to 16 generate

instantiate_h_pipelined_reg : regn
    generic map ( N=> b, init => bzeros )
    port map ( clk => clk , rst => '0', en => '1',
       input => h_blk_pipelined_input(i - 1),                                            
       output=> h_blk_pipelined_input(i));                                          
end generate instantiate_h_m_qa_pipeline_registers;
```

The signals are now defined as:

```
type std_logic_block is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(iw - 1 downto 0) ;
type partial_pipeline_registers_type is array (0 to 16) of std_logic_block;
signal h_blk_pipelined_input : partial_pipeline_registers_type;
```

And the error I get from XST is:

**ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - ((where the register part is)) Type of input is incompatible with type of h_blk_pipelined_input.**

I'm able to do everything I was able to do before, using ()() syntax instead of ( , ) so I haven't lost anything going this way, but it still doesn't resolve my problem.

**EDIT:**

Took it a step further and used a conversion function on the input => and output => arguments for the register instantiation, using a function to convert between the array type and just a std_logic_vector the size that I need.  It fixed the 'input => ' part, but..

**Actual associated with Formal OUT mode Signal 'output' may not be a type conversion or function call. (LRM 4.3.2.2)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things to play right, I had to use a function to flatten and unflatten my data interacting with the register instantiation.

The real issue boiled down to me having an array of std_logic_vector() that resulted in a large vector which the register instantiation needed to have.. and then the register was giving me back the vector, which I needed to put in to an array of vectors.

Creating a function and then doing the following is working great.

```
      input => blk2vec(h_blk_pipelined_input(i - 1)),                        
      vec2blk(output) => h_blk_pipelined_input(i));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that this doesn't synthesize.

Comment: But, using another intermediate signal, and then using a vec2blk type function there, does work

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
TYPE reg512_type IS ARRAY(0 TO 15) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE partial_pipeline_registers_type IS ARRAY(0 TO 16) OF reg512_type;
```

The code on that Xilinx site obviously isn't tested.  Since `ARRAY OF ...` are types, not subtypes, their code shouldn't compile.

EDIT: These custom types aren't going to play well with existing IP components, but that's ok, the compiler can infer registers easily enough.  Try:

```
instantiate_h_m_qa_pipeline_registers: FOR i IN 1 TO 16 GENERATE

instantiate_h_pipelined_reg : PROCESS (clk)
BEGIN
    IF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
        h_blk_pipelined_input(i) <= h_blk_pipelined_input(i - 1);
    END IF;
END GENERATE instantiate_h_m_qa_pipeline_registers;
```

Comment: I think we're getting close here.. see my question edits at bottom of question for errors I'm getting now

Comment: @Nektarios: VHDL is very picky about types.  Even types which are compatible, like `UNSIGNED` and `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, can't be used interchangeably.  But you can cast between them (casting in VHDL looks like a C++ constructor-style cast).  Or you can change the data type of the component parameters to `reg512_type`.  To do that, you'll have to move the type declarations to a library module so they're visible to multiple components.

Comment: so, my register is defined with  "input    : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);" .. are you saying its possible that when I instantiate one of these registers and set up " input => h_blk.... " I can somehow recast my h_blk_pipelined_input to be seen as std_logic_vector(size) instead of an array of smaller std_logic_vectors?  How would I do that exactly?  Thanks